# remove word using "grep -v" exact match only

Tags: grep

How can I do an exact match using `grep -v`?

For example: the following command

```sh
for i in 0 0.3 a; do echo $i | grep -v "0"; done
```

returns `a`. But I want it to return `0.3 a`.

Using

```sh
grep -v "0\b"
```

is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for i in 0 0.3 a; do echo $i | grep -v "^0$"; done`

You need to match the start and end of the string with `^` and `$`

So, we say "match the beginning of a line, the char `0` and then the end of the line.

> > $ for i in 0 0.3 a; do echo $i | grep -v "^0$"; done
> >
> > 0.3
> >
> > a

Comment: thanks! I tried "\n" "\b" "\r", and I didnt think about "$". Good exercise to check the man page :-)

Answer (score 1):

The safest way for single-column entries is using awk. Normally, I would use grep with the `-w` flag, but since you want to exactly match an integer that could be part of a float, it is a bit more tricky. The <dot>-character makes it hard to use any of

```
grep -vw 0
grep -v '\b0\b'
grep -v '\<0\>'
```

The proposed solution also will only work on perfect lines, what if you have a lost space in front or after your zero. The line will fail. So the safest would be:

**single column file:**

```
awk '($1!="0")' file
```

**multi-word file:** (adopt the variable `FS` to fit your needs)

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) if($i == "0") next}1' file
```

Comment: yes, I also started with -w option. But anything related to floating values is a pain in bash. One day I will learn awk, I swear.
Thanks